# Get previous 30 days starting time in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get previous 30 days current date and time.. But, its not something else

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

This is returning

```
Tue Jul 21 04:41:20 IST 2015
```

Is there any wrong

Comment: JodaTime, Java 8's Time API, Calendar, anything but THAT!

Comment: @MadProgrammer, plz tell me the issue with the above code

Comment: Date/Time arithmetic is wrapped by a bunch of rules and conditions which you've just gone and ignored.  This kind of method ALWAYS results in crap results

Comment: The jodatime library is much easier for date/time handling in java. I assume in your code the calculation is done with int and then gives a numeric overflow, try long instead.

Answer (score 8):

Never, never, ever do anything like `System.currentTimeMillis() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 100`, there are so many rules with time manipulation that this kind of thing never works well

## Java 8's Time API

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(30);
```

Which outputs `2015-06-01T16:15:54.868`

## [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime();
ldt = ldt.minusDays(30);
```

Which outputs `2015-06-01T16:18:22.489`

## Calendar

If you're really desperate

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Which outputs `Mon Jun 01 16:19:45 EST 2015`

Comment: the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) says **For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds.**   is this the case of OP ?

Comment: @theRoot I don't think so, as Andre pointed out in the comments, it's more likely they run into a integer overflow issue, but having said that, millisecond manipulation like that is never a good idea, there aren't always 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hours in day.  Date/Time is so screwed, there is actually 365.25 days in year, which makes for 30.4375 days in a month and 4.348214285714286 weeks in a month ... sorry, but that's just screwy.  Better to use a dedicated library and save your sanity

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache Commons Library **(commons-lang)**.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date dateBefore30Days = DateUtils.addDays(currentDate, -30);
```

See this link for more details: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 2):

The code which you have provided `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` might give incorrect results because it wont consider any date/time logic implemented by Java. That will give only Mathematically correct result but not Logically correct result.

You can use `java.util.Calendar` class without using any external library.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // get Calendar Instance
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -30); // add -30 days as you need to subtract 30 days
Date dateRequired = calendar.getTime(); // get the new date from modified cal object.
```